# Unmarshall JSON to subtypes with different field type jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I receive a JSON array of objects which all have field **content**, but the type of this field may differ:

```
[
    {
        "id": "primaryBodyHeader",
        "type": "RichText",
        "content": "<h1>Alice's Adventures in Wonderland</h1>"
    },
    {
        "id": "1027",
        "type": "RichText",
        "content": {
            "value": "RVMtMTk=",
            "contentType": "DynamicContent"
        }
    }
]
```

And I have the bean:

```
public abstract class LandingPageContentItem {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String content;
}
```

At least I want to map **content** to a text field when it is a text (null for non-text content)

At most, I want to map different kinds of items to different subclasses according to the type of field **content** - TextContentItem, ComplexContentItem or so. @JsonSubTypes can't do this

Is there a way to do it without custom deserializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know (or have no control of) what might be in `content` field then I'd suggest you to map raw [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) like this

```
public static class LandingPageContentItem {
    private final String id;
    private final String type;
    private final JsonNode content;

    @JsonCreator
    public LandingPageContentItem(
            @JsonProperty("id") final String id, 
            @JsonProperty("type") final String type, 
            @JsonProperty("content") final JsonNode content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.content = content;
    }

    /* some logic here */
}
```

And then you can read it normally

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<LandingPageContentItem> items = 
    mapper.readValue(node, new TypeReference<List<LandingPageContentItem>>() {});
```

Later on you can verify if `JsonNode` is of expected type.

```
if (content.isTextual()) {
    // do something with content.asText(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without writing a custom deserializer, the best I can think of is:

```
public class LandingPageContentItem {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private Object content;
}
```

Then just use `if(item.content instanceof String)` and `if(item.content instanceof Map)` to handle it from there.

Comment: @vsminkov has a better answer.  `JsonNode` is probably better than `Object` in most cases.